# Disabling recaptcha on certain pages

Tags: joomla-3.x

Users are complaining that, since they must be registred to post an article, there is no need to have a captcha (google re-captcah) in the article creation page on the front-end...
Does anyone know a way to restrict the pages on which the captcha will be activated ? I haven't seen anything like that :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Articles Global Configuration. In Editing Layout tab set Allow Captcha on submit to None Selected.